# LWJGL 3 Mouse Movement

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I want to implement a FPS style mouse look in my lwjgl3 java application, but since there isn't any `Mouse.getDX()` or `Mouse.getDY()`, I'm looking for a different approach using the glfw bindings.
I wrote this method that gets called in my `update()` method:

```
public double[] pollMouseDelta() {
    DoubleBuffer x = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(1);
    DoubleBuffer y = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(1);

    glfwGetCursorPos(WINDOW, x, y);
    x.rewind();
    y.rewind();

    double tempX = mouseX;
    double tempY = mouseY;

    mouseX = x.get();
    mouseY = y.get();

    return new double[] {
           mouseX - tempX,
           mouseY - tempY
    };
}
```

where `mouseX` and `mouseY` are global variables.

In my update method I do the following:

```
double[] mouseDelta = pollMouseDelta();

camera.rotate(Camera.Direction.LEFT_RIGHT, (float) (0.2f * -mouseDelta[0]));
camera.rotate(Camera.Direction.UP_DOWN, (float) (0.2f * mouseDelta[1]));

camera.update();
```

I also set the `GLFW_CURSOR` mode to `GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED`.
But the camera is stuttering and making big jumps. Also, sometimes the mouse seems to be inverted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're confusing me. `Mouse` is an LWJGL class, which definitely has `Mouse.getDX/DY()`.

Comment: They removed all classes with static methods that had to do something with the window system, since they use glfw now to support multiple windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code snippet of with the basis for my FPS style camera.  As you can see I am calculating the delta of the mouse position with the center of the screen along the X and Y axis.

You can see in my System.out.println calls the values I am calculating for deltas and the fact that it should be rotating by this amount.  I then multiply these values by my sensitivity and rotate the camera by this amount.

```
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetCursorPos;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class Main {

    // We need to strongly reference callback instances.
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Sys.getVersion() + "!");

        try {
            init();
            loop();

            // Release window and window callbacks
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            keyCallback.release();
        } finally {
            // Terminate GLFW and release the GLFWerrorfun
            glfwTerminate();
            errorCallback.release();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = errorCallbackPrint(System.err));

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( glfwInit() != GL11.GL_TRUE )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure our window
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);


        int WIDTH = 800;
        int HEIGHT = 600;

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
                if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
            }
        });

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
                window,
                (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2,
                (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2
        );

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the ContextCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GLContext.createFromCurrent();


        // Create a FloatBuffer to hold our vertex data
        FloatBuffer vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
        // Add vertices of the triangle
        vertices.put(new float[]
                {
                        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
                        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
                        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
                });
        // Rewind the vertices
        vertices.rewind();


        int vbo = glGenBuffers();
        int vao = glGenVertexArrays();

        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        final String vertex_shader =
                "#version 410\n" +
                        "in vec3 vp;\n" +
                        "void main () {\n" +
                        "  gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 1.0);\n" +
                        "}";

        final String frag_shader =
                "#version 400\n"    +
                        "out vec4 frag_colour;" +
                        "void main () {"         +
                        "  frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);" +
                        "}";

        int shader_programme = glCreateProgram();


        int vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertex_shader);
        glCompileShader (vertexShaderID);

        if(glGetShaderi(vertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0){
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderID, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glAttachShader (shader_programme, vertexShaderID);

        int fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, frag_shader);
        glCompileShader (fragmentShaderID);

        if(glGetShaderi(fragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0){
            System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShaderID, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glAttachShader (shader_programme, fragmentShaderID);

        glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

        if(glGetProgrami(shader_programme, GL_LINK_STATUS) == 0){
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_programme, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glValidateProgram(shader_programme);

        if(glGetProgrami(shader_programme, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == 0){
            System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_programme, 1024));
            System.exit(1);
        }

        boolean mouseLocked = false;
        double newX = 400;
        double newY = 300;

        double prevX = 0;
        double prevY = 0;

        boolean rotX = false;
        boolean rotY = false;

        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);


        while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {

            if (glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_1) == GLFW_PRESS) {
                glfwSetCursorPos(window, 800/2, 600/2);

                mouseLocked = true;
            }

            if (mouseLocked){
                DoubleBuffer x = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(1);
                DoubleBuffer y = BufferUtils.createDoubleBuffer(1);

                glfwGetCursorPos(window, x, y);
                x.rewind();
                y.rewind();

                newX = x.get();
                newY = y.get();

                double deltaX = newX - 400;
                double deltaY = newY - 300;

                rotX = newX != prevX;
                rotY = newY != prevY;

                if(rotY) {
                    System.out.println("ROTATE Y AXIS: " + deltaY);

                }
                if(rotX) {
                    System.out.println("ROTATE X AXIS: " + deltaX);
                }

                prevX = newX;
                prevY = newY;


                System.out.println("Delta X = " + deltaX + " Delta Y = " + deltaY);

                glfwSetCursorPos(window, 800/2, 600/2);
            }

            // wipe the drawing surface clear
            glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glUseProgram (shader_programme);
            glBindVertexArray (vao);
            // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
            glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            // update other events like input handling
            glfwPollEvents ();
            // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
            glfwSwapBuffers (window);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, I was very busy this week. Anyway, thank you for your quick reply. It works fine now!!

Comment: I have just one more question: How did you implement this method with callbacks? Are you just setting the newX / newY variable or are you using the method suggested by Zeroni in the LWJGL forum? I'm interested in this because I also tried his method, the stuttering was gone but I still see a big jump right at the beginning and the mouse is sometimes inverted.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I am working on something exactly like this right now.</s>

The idea is to reset the camera position to the center every time you loop, like this:

```
glfwSetCursorPos(YOUR WINDOW HANDLE, YOUR_WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, YOU_WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
```

This way your delta is always in comparison to the distance from the center of the screen.  So that should solve your jumping around issues.

**Edit (Leaving my answer above for posterity):**

OK, so I was also having this same issue as you. Disregard what I have said above its not quite right.

I ended up implementing something similar to what you are doing but received the same results where the delta is too big so the camera is moving much too fast.

What I did to fix this was actually do the mouse polling every single frame and calculating the "delta" with the following operation:

```
deltaX = currentMousePos.x - lastFrameMousePos.x
deltaY = currentMousePos.y - lastFrameMousePos.y
```

Now the delta should be sufficiently small and also calculated per frame.

Then for calculating my angle of rotation I use this:

```
deltaPos.getY() * sensitivity * Time.getDelta()
```

Where Time.getDelta() is the time diff between each frame loop.  What I end up with is a fairly smooth camera albeit not perfect yet.

Let me know if you want anymore info.

**Edit 2:**

Check out this link which has my similar issues [Link](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5597.0) on the LWJGL forums.  I do actually have this working nicely now. I'll post a separate answer with code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and get a weird console output: The mouse is making a big jump at the beginning of the game, mouse delta is more than 800 for each X and Y coordinate. If I restart the game, the mouse seems to be inverted sometimes.

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer and let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. Are you using calbacks or do you pull the cursor position directly?

Comment: I have both styles working. Check out my second update. Also, have you tried just multiplying by a lower sensitivity.  The sensitivity I am using is float sensitivity = 0.0005f;

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get your mouse position is to extend the GLFWCursorPosCallback class and then just use the x and y values that it provides in it's invoke method.

A good tutorial on doing this can be found here:

[LWJGL 3 Mouse Position](http://tutorialedge.net/lwjgl-3-getting-mouse-current-position-tutorial)